# Nested Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array soter and a counter array. I want to get the the number of `name` which the count array will provide me. Is it correct ? I am a bit confused about the output. Can someone enligten me on this nested array loop in JavaScript ?

```
var soter = ['bp','mf','cc'],

count = [0,0,0]; 

for(var y = 0 ; y < soter.length; y++) {            
   for(var i = 0 ;i < data.SO_Ter.length; i++) {
     if(data.SO_Ter[i].name == soter[y]) {
        count[y]++;
```

Comment: Can you give additional information on what the `data.SO_Ter` is?

Comment: `data` is an object. `SO_Ter` is the child object. `name` is the property of the child object

Comment: Seems fine to me, you will get in count an int with the number of times the string in 'soter' appears in data. Make sure the lenghts of soter and count are the same.
What does your result looks like?

Comment: @AAlferez Can you provide a full fledge answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code seems correct to me, supposing the well formed object **data** and child **SO_Ter** .

So you go through the outer loop, positions 0 to 2, and for each one of them you will check that each of the items in data.SO_Ter is equal to the soter value.
If you find that value, you increment the count in 1.

Does it make sense?

To make it easier, it would be like:

```
for(var i = 0 ;i < data.SO_Ter.length; i++) {
     if(data.SO_Ter[i].name == soter[0]) {
        count[0]++;
for(var i = 0 ;i < data.SO_Ter.length; i++) {
     if(data.SO_Ter[i].name == soter[1]) {
        count[1]++;
for(var i = 0 ;i < data.SO_Ter.length; i++) {
     if(data.SO_Ter[i].name == soter[2]) {
        count[2]++;
```

So since you do it 3 times, you just replace those with an outer for loop.

**UPDATE**

count[0] represents how many times the word 'bp' has been found

count[1] represents how many times the word 'mf' has been found

count[2] represents how many times the word 'cc' has been found

Comment: What does the `count[0], count[1], count[2]` represent ?

Comment: You are accessing the count array you created in your code, positions 0, 1, 2, which gets the value of that position.

Comment: count array and soter array both have the same lenght because count[0] represents the count of the times the word on soter[0] appears, same for count[1] and soter[1] and so on.

Comment: So the `count[2]++` sets the number of `cc`found in `data.SO_Ter[i].name` ? Right ?

Comment: count[2]++ will increase the count on position 2, which means that another 'cc' has been found when compared to data.SO_Ter[i], correct

Comment: Btw, which one represents the outer for loop ?

Comment: Even though you are looping through soter positions, soter and count have the same lenght because there needs to be one count per word.
So the outer loop refers to both soter and count arrays